# Scrollview stopped working when I added tabs to the actionbar

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, android-scrollview

**Background:** I develop for Android 4 (SDK 15) and use the native actionbar. In one of my activities I have a fragment with a scrollview as the root element. The fragment fills the content. I do not set a layout for the activity, I only add the fragment. It all works fine.

**Problem:** When I add tabs to the actionbar the scroll view doesn't work anymore. The scrollbar shows up when I tap the screen but there is no scrolling.

I have a second fragment for the second tab. It is a WebView and it scrolls perfectly.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone have any idea?

The tabs are added with this code:

```
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Set the name of the current entity as the title of the action bar.
    final TextView textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.action_bar_text_view, null);
    textView.setText(getGuideContext().getSelectedEntity().getName(
            getGuidePreferences().getNameLang()));
    actionBar.setCustomView(textView);

    // Show the actionbar now that the text view is set up.
    actionBar.show();

    // Set the tabs.
    final Entity entity = getGuideContext().getSelectedEntity();

    final DetailsTabListener factsListener = new DetailsTabListener(
            DetailsMode.FACTS, entity, details);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getString(R.string.details_tab_facts))
            .setTabListener(factsListener));

    final DetailsTabListener webListener = new DetailsTabListener(
            DetailsMode.WEB, entity, details);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
            .setText(getString(R.string.details_tab_web))
            .setTabListener(webListener));
```

This is the DetailsTabListener:

```
public class DetailsTabListener implements TabListener {

/** The current details mode. */
private final DetailsMode detailsMode;

/** A reference to the details of the current entity. */
private final WeakReference<Details> detailsRef;

/** A reference to the current entity. */
private final WeakReference<Entity> entityRef;

/** Holds a reference to the fragment this listener last created. */
private WeakReference<Fragment> fragmentRef;

/**
 * The constructor.
 * 
 * @param detailsMode
 *            the current details mode, i.e. the type of fragment this
 *            listener is listening to, must not be null
 * @param entity
 *            the currently selected entity, must not be null
 * @param details
 *            details for the current entity, must not be null
 */
public DetailsTabListener(final DetailsMode detailsMode,
        final Entity entity, final Details details) {

    if ((detailsMode == null) || (entity == null) || (details == null)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "None of the parameters detailsMode, entity or details can be null.");
    }

    this.detailsMode = detailsMode;
    this.entityRef = new WeakReference<Entity>(entity);
    this.detailsRef = new WeakReference<Details>(details);
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    if (fragmentRef == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Scroll to top.
    final Fragment fragment = fragmentRef.get();
    if (fragment instanceof ScrollToTopInterface) {
        ((ScrollToTopInterface) fragment).scrollToTop();
    }
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    // Sets a fragment that was created earlier if there is one.
    Fragment fragment = null;
    if (fragmentRef != null) {
        fragment = fragmentRef.get();
    }

    // Creates and adds a new fragment if there is none, or attach the old
    // one if it exists.
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = DetailsFragmentFactory.createFragment(detailsMode,
                entityRef.get(), detailsRef.get());
        fragmentRef = new WeakReference<Fragment>(fragment);
        ft.add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "");
    } else {
        ft.attach(fragment);
    }
}

/** {@inheritDoc} */
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    // Detach the fragment if there is one.
    if (fragmentRef != null) {
        ft.detach(fragmentRef.get());
    }
}
```

}

This is the layout of the fragment:

```
<ScrollView 
android:id="@+id/details_facts_scroll_view"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/details_facts_margin_top_bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_facts_margin_top_bottom"       
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_facts_header_margin_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/details_length"
            style="@style/details_fact_header"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"                 
            android:text="@string/details_weight"
            style="@style/details_fact_header"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_length"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            style="@style/details_fact"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_weight"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"                 
            style="@style/details_fact"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_facts_header_margin_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"                 
            android:text="@string/details_wingspan"
            style="@style/details_fact_header"
        />

        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="0.5"        
            android:text="@string/details_age"
            style="@style/details_fact_header"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >         

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_wingspan"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"                 
            style="@style/details_fact"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/details_age"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"        
            style="@style/details_fact"
        />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_photograph_section_header"
        android:text="@string/details_photograph_section_header"
        style="@style/details_fact_section_header"
    />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/details_photograph_section_divider"
        style="@style/divider"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/details_image_content_description"
        android:id="@+id/details_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/details_facts_margin_left_right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_image_text"
        style="@style/details_image_text"
    />


    <TextView
        android:text="@string/details_taxonomy_section_header"
        style="@style/details_fact_section_header"
    />

    <View
        style="@style/divider"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_facts_header_margin_top"
        android:text="@string/details_english"
        style="@style/details_fact_header"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_taxonomy_english"
        style="@style/details_fact"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_facts_header_margin_top"       
        android:text="@string/details_latin"
        style="@style/details_fact_header"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_taxonomy_latin"
        style="@style/details_fact"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/details_facts_header_margin_top"       
        android:text="@string/details_swedish"
        style="@style/details_fact_header"
    />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/details_taxonomy_swedish"
        style="@style/details_fact"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to post some code if you want any help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I added some code. Hard to know what is interesting though. Do you miss anything?

Comment: are you trying to set a scrollview in a tabhost?

Comment: No, I am using the tabs in the actionbar and I have a scrollview in the fragment that is added to the content of the activity. I've added a code sample of the adding of the fragment to the content.

Comment: When I add a second fragment that contains a web view it scrolls perfectly. I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Can you post the full code for your tab listener?  Also, have tried ft.Replace() instead of ft.Add()?

Comment: Yes of course, it's added.

Comment: I've tried to use replace instead of add. Unfortunatley it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I've kind of fixed this problem now.

It seems like the scrollview doesn't know about the tabs and therefore thinks that the layout fits and that no scrolling is necessary. If I add some more views at the bottom of the layout I can scroll again. Or if I remove the tabs the scroll works (as stated in the question).

My workaround is to add a large space view at the bottom of the layout. But if anyone knows why the scrollview behaves this way I am still interested. I have a feeling that there is a more elegant solution to the problem.